# Programmatically trigger button on a website

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-calendar-api

I am trying to programmatically click one of the date range buttons (day, week, month,...) on the [google calendar page](https://calendar.google.com).  My attempts at programmatically triggering the button callback have all failed.  It is worth noting that the button's html structure is actually a div with attached event listeners and several child divs (I posted it below).

What I have tried:

```
var month = document.getElementsByClassName("goog-inline-block goog-imageless-button goog-imageless-button-collapse-left goog-imageless-button-collapse-right")[1];

// (1)
month.click();    

// (2)
var click = new Event("click", {"bubbles":true, "cancelable":false});
month.dispatchEvent(click);

// (3)
var over = new Event("mouseover", {"bubbles":true, "cancelable":false});
var down = new Event("mousedown", {"bubbles":true, "cancelable":false});
var up = new Event("mouseup", {"bubbles":true, "cancelable":false});
month.dispatchEvent(over);
month.dispatchEvent(down);
month.dispatchEvent(up);

// (4)
coords = month.getBoundingClientRect(); 
    // I repeated 2 & 3, but set the event's clientX & clientY attributes
    var click = new Event("click", {"bubbles":true, "cancelable":false});
    click.clientX = coords.left + n // n is some offset within coords.left & coords.right
    click.clientY = coords.top + m // m is some offset within coords.top & coords.bottom
    month.dispatchEvent(click);

// (5)
// Tried using analogous methods in JQuery
var $month = // jquery selector producing month btn
$month.trigger("click");

// (6)
// Repeated 1-5 on the child elements
```

Is there anything else I can do to trigger the button's callback?  Is there another way I can emulate a user pressing it?  for simplicity sake lets assume my script looks like this:

```
// script injected into google cal page after all content has properly loaded
 var month = document.getElementsByClassName("goog-inline-block goog-imageless-button goog-imageless-button-collapse-left goog-imageless-button-collapse-right")[1];
 var delay = 1000;

 setTimeout(function(){
     // code that successfully triggers month's callback.
 },delay);
```

The button has the following html structure:

```
<div class="goog-inline-block goog-imageless-button goog-imageless-button-collapse-left goog-imageless-button-collapse-right" role="button" style="-webkit-user-select: none;" aria-pressed="false" tabindex="0">
  <div class="goog-inline-block goog-imageless-button-outer-box">
    <div class="goog-inline-block goog-imageless-button-inner-box">
      <div class="goog-imageless-button-pos">
        <div class="goog-imageless-button-top-shadow">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="goog-imageless-button-content">Month</div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't directly answer the question, but this seems to do the trick.... append `%7Cmonth`, `%7Cday`, `%7Ccustom,4`, `%7Clist` etc to the google calendar URL.  This should be safe, since it comes after the `#main_7` bookmark URL, which shouldn't force a reload of the page.

Comment: That does help!  For months other than the current month the patttern, Cmonth-3+day1+day2+day3 must be used; ex: (Cmonth-3+23901+23938+23905).  The day1, day2, day3 can be obtained from the ids of the cells in the mini graph.  Matching that pattern can be tricky.  I would really prefer to invoke the callback as if the user had clicked the button.  Also I am very curious why the events I am creating/ dispatching are not triggering the proper callback.

Comment: Using the Chrome debugger you can put a DOM element break point on attribute change and that might help.  I put one on the button attributes.  Unfortunately the breakpoint is cryptic even when beautified... https://jsfiddle.net/agdo3r2r/

Comment: Event listener breakpoints (bottom right) are nice as well, you can put a breakpoint on any mouse clicks and trace which events are getting triggered.

Comment: Are you sure the click listener is on the outer DIV and not on one of the inner DIVs?